# error when compiling my angular application suddenly

Tags: angular, node-modules, package.json

i have an issue while compiling my angular app suddenly , i didn't add any modifications

i will give a screenshot of the errors and maybe you can help me

i tryed to delete node_modules and install again with npm i ,

i deleted node_modules and package.lock.json ,

and i cleaned the cache but still the same probleme ,

i'm trying to figure out why .

[appmodule error suddenly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40tyf.png)

[npm i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uURck.png)

[the error after ng s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSaFn.png)